# Tax Calculate Incorrectly - WooCommerce

Tags: e-commerce, woocommerce

All
I am running the WordPress **3.4.1** with the WooCommerce **1.5.8**, as of this writing.

i just more confuse in **Tax Amount** 
I need help with a Woocommerce problem.
Woocommerce has a "taxable" status for shipping. This option should include tax calculation on shipping (which has to be shown by law in the Netherlands).
However I have selected this option, however the system only **calculations tax** on the items products, **NOT on the shipping costs**.
So the tax calculation should be: 21% of (product price + shipping costs) while now it is 21% of product price.

**So the problem is,** 
the tax amount now is 21% of the product: 99.95 - (99.95/1.21) = 17.35.
In the shipping settings in woocommerce you can set your shipping to be added to tax calculation (tax status: taxable).
If this option is selected, the tax calculation should actually be: 
product costs + shipping costs / ((product costs + shipping costs)/1.21).
So the total of products + shipping = 105.90. 
Which means the tax calculation should be 105.90 - (105.90/1.21) = 18.38

Right now 
it calculates 99.95 - (99.95/1.21) =17.35 
I would like it to calculate 105.90 -(105.90/1.22) = 18.38.

**Anyone Help Please ???**

Answer (score 2):

After too many research I got solution and its so simple...

Follow below steps..

1)Go to woocommerce > settings.

2)Under Tax tab,there are Tax Options and Tax rates links available.Under Tax options,select shipping tax class..!

3)In Tax rates,click on your  previously selected  tax class and just checked checkbox under shipping column..

So, Now your tax calculation is: 21% of (Cart Subtotal + shipping costs)..

For detail with screenshots please visit : http://maishidh.blogspot.in/

Answer (score 0):

I was looking though the docs and it seems to me you might need some hard coding done. Here are the API documentation in regards of Woo commerce Tax Api. Look at line 503 and line 508. Maybe change those variables and see what you might get.

http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Tax.html#_calc_shipping_tax